# overflow scroll doesn't work within fixed div?

Tags: html, css

In my **demo http://jsfiddle.net/batfafpf/2/** my modal is unscrollable even I set it to overflow-y:scroll. Not sure why, probably the fixed positin of the parent is causing the problem.

```
#dateTimeModal > div{
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: When you give overflow you need to mention a certain height for the div too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scroll event is not working due to two mistakes in style.

1. Remove, `pointer-events: none;`
2. make fixed height of your wrapper div.

Here is what it should be.

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;  
}

#dateTimeModal > div{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `overflow-y: scroll;` to this class and remove  **pointer-events: none;**

```
.modalDialog {
        position: fixed;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index: 99999;
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;

        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/batfafpf/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the earlier poster, remove pointer-events: none. And change height to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a height, to command browsers to make div able to scroll when the height set, exceeded.

```
#dateTimeModal > div{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height: 200px;
}
```